# Rails scaffold built table called assets - now route errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used scaffold to build a table called "assets".  The files were created. The "rake db:create" worked fine.  I added "  resources :assets" to my routes.rb file.  I now get route errors.  I ran "rake routes" and none of the routes for "assets" show up.

Is it bad to use a table name "assets"?
Or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asset pipeline uses /assets by default.

You can either change the default assets path by using this in `application.rb`:

`config.assets.prefix = '/something-else'`

Or change the routing for your assets resource by using:

`resources :assets, :path => 'something-else'`

edit: Actually the second option is probably the better choice because I forgot that `asset_path` is available by default and belongs to the asset pipeline. If you changed your default assets prefix and used `asset_path @asset` hoping to generate a link to `assets#show` then it might cause problems.

Use the `:as` option in your routes to change the path/url methods it generates.

`resources :assets, :path => 'things', :as => 'things'`

`things_path` results in /things and routes to the index action of the assets controller

`thing_path @asset` results in /things/:id and routes to the show action of the assets controller

etc.

Comment: If I change the routing for my assets table, do I have to rename any folders or files?